# How to select "moments to match" in simulated method of moments (SMM)?

Tags: econometrics, simulation, generalized-moments

Unlike DSGE model ,which indicates which moment to match explicitly ([this paper](http://www.cireqmontreal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ruge_smm.pdf)), the standard of "moment selection" in quantitative econ model is ambiguous. Certain parameter can influence more than one moment, especially when you merely rely on the cross-sectional heterogeneties in microdata to construct moments (see [this paper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109115/website/oswald_jmp.pdf)). Visiting through the multiple parameter space is often computational infeasible.In this case, is there some thumb rule to guide your selection?

Comment: Typically when using algorithms related to moment matching, people often tend to use the lowest order moments that get the job done. While often a sensible choice it's not always guaranteed to be the most efficient -- but on the other hand efficiency isn't the only consideration.

Comment: Well, I have admit my question is more related to economics than to statistics. The mainstream economic literatures typically use mean, variance and 1st-order autoregression coefficient as the target moments. But what I want to know is , when the heterogeneties matters (say the homeownership over 25-29age group and 45-49 age group), How do we choose the moments? Or in some cases, a model parameter has impact many target moments, what kinds of optimization approach we should pick up? Some suggest that the Simulated Annealing can be a solution. Any further suggestion?

Comment: That looks like good information to put into your question.